# Azure Service Bus Subscription Filter Arm Template not creating $Default filter

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am trying to deploy a rule to an Azure Topic Subscription. The arm template deploys the rule "workday" **without** the $Default rule, however, the subscription never gets the message when I publish to the Topic. It only works when I add the $Default Rule.

I am using Cerebrata Cerulean. When I add the subscription via this tool and add the workday rule it automatically creates the $Default rule!!

[image]

This is my arm template. I cannot add a $Default Rule as it wont let me.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your complete ARM template?

Answer (score 0):

> Create/Update of a $Default rule is not allowed.

Each newly created topic subscription has an **initial default subscription rule**. If you don't explicitly specify a filter condition for the rule, the applied filter is the `true` filter that enables all messages to be selected into the subscription. The default rule has no associated annotation action.

Use the ARM [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-servicebus-topic-subscription-sqlfilter) to add sql filter, just the name is not `$default`.

```
"resources": [
     {
         "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
         "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusTopicSubscriptionName'), '-filter')]",
         "type": "Rules",
         "dependsOn": [
             "[parameters('serviceBusTopicSubscriptionName')]"
         ],
         "properties": {
             "filter": {
                 "sqlExpression": "[parameters('serviceBusTopicSubscriptionSqlFilter')]"
                 }
            }
         }
]
```

The output is as below:

[image]